# fb://profile/idUser doesn't work in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I can not open a link like fb://profile/idIser on the native facebook app anymore.

It was working two days ago...

Does anyone know how to open the fb native app with a user profile url?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you get an error? What happens when you try to open that?

Comment: This is an undocumented feature that you should not rely on as it can change at any time without notice.

Comment: So... How can I open a user profile on fb app from  my app?